# Huge It video gallery plugin: How to return results as random?

Tags: wordpress

I have a video gallery that uses shortcode i wanted to know if there wAs a way i can add a random code to that shortcode to get a random result/video everytime the page is refreshed heres the shortcode [huge_it_videogallery id="2"] im using the plugin hugh it videogallery

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on the structure of the plugin. These are your options:

1. Check if the Plugin offers this functionality as a backend setting
2. Check if the Plugin has any hooks for adding randomness in a clean way
3. You can modify the Plugin source code and implement randomness (updates will not be possible any more then)
4. You may contact the Plugin developers and make a feature request
5. Choose another plugin or make your own